# Keep running a C# application

Tags: c#

I don't know how and where to start with this problem. I have created an app using C# and I want the app to start when computer starts on and keep running and the only way to close the application is when you shut down the computer.

What is the best way to do it? Can we hide our application and keep running in background without popping out to user?

Can I do it using a loop which is always true?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service you can try and create it as a service as long as the user doesn't need to interact with the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is typically handled using a [Windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx), set to start on boot.  Note that there are ways for an administrator of the machine to stop/restart the service so the service needs to be able to handle that type of interaction gracefully.  Similarly, a sufficiently privileged person could kill off any running application at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it as windows service.

Answer (score 0):

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service you can try and create it as a service as long as the user doesn't need to interact with the program

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a windows service as already mentioned, you can make it a system tray app which can run in the background from computer startup routine. The benefit being if your app requires user interaction at any point, it can be done with a system tray app but not with a windows service.

Check out this question and accepted answer for more info - [Put a program in the system tray at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283632/put-a-program-in-the-system-tray-at-startup)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windows scheduler to start the app on boot or login, at least with the more recent versions of Windows. I don't know off the top of my head what version of Windows that was introduced.

Using a service as the other answers suggest is also an option. Visual Studio has a project template for created Windows Services, then you can use `sc create` from the windows Command Prompt to create the service, or create an installer project if you're feeling fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Scheduler by either typing "task" into the Start Menu search bar, or by opening All Programs - Accessories - System Tools.

- Select 'Create Basic Task' from the right hand pane and the 'Create Basic Task Wizard will open.
- Type a 'Name' and 'Description' for your new task and click Next
- Select when you would like the event/task to run and click next. I am selecting daily.
- Select exact time when you want to run the application and click next.
- Select action and click next. I am selecting here Start a program.
- Click ‘Browse’ and select the exe file form the folder and click next. Click Finish.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question, but it might be useful in relattion to it, so I am leaving it. However, you have included another non-disclosed link to your blog, which does not contain any more useful information than is here. to avoid this being flagged as spam, I am removing the link for you.